# Why does my obj become transparent when I import

Tags: texturing, objects, transparency

When I do import my obj files it's become transparent in some part like in the picture

[image] I try to fix at here but all I can do is changing the subsurface color but I want the texture thing (I already have the texture but don't know how to put it in the transparent thing)
[image]

Comment: You have used an alpha channel. Alpha is used to make part of a mesh transparent. That's why it's becoming transparent.

Comment: how to fix that?

Comment: Remove the Alpha Input to principled bsdf. If that doesn't solve it, please provide the blend file

Comment: Since the hat is visible behind the hair, I don't think it is transparent because of the alpha - this looks like backface culling. If he changed the viewport shading to _Solid_ or _Rendered_ the transparency would be gone, it's only shown in the _Material Preview_. If the transparency is caused by the _Alpha Channel_ it would be black in _Material Preview_ (not transparent), unnoticable in _Solid_ view and be transparent in _Rendered_ view. Looking at the image, if the hat is supposed to have a texture that's not black, than it might be a combination of backface culling and alpha transparency.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like *Backface Culling*, i.e. when you see the backside of a face it is invisible. This helps for example if you want to see if some face normals are pointing in the wrong direction.

To disable *Backface Culling*, choose the material in the *Material Tab* and go to *Viewport Display* > *Settings* > *Backface Culling* and disable it (that's Cycles, in Eeevee it's in the overall *Settings* of the material).

But: if your material is invisible from the outside this presumably means that the normals on this object are turned inside out. In the *Viewport Overlays* you can enable "Face Orientation", the outside of faces are shwon in blue, the inside in red. I guess the faces of that object will show up in red.

To correct that go into *Edit Mode*, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to *Recalculate Normals*. You can tick *Inside* here if they are still red.

If only some faces are red and some are blue and recalculating normals doesn't make them uniformly red or blue, you can select the faces you want to change, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the *Normals* menu and choose "Flip".

EDIT: As I commented above, if the material has a texture which is supposedly not black, than you might have a combination of *Backface Culling* and *Alpha Transparency*.

Your screenshot shows that hat is transparent/invisible in front of the hair but all black behind the hair. *Backface Culling* and *Alpha Transparency* are shown differently in different Viewport Shading:

1. In *Solid* view, you only see the faces without any transparency.
2. In *Material Preview*, *Backface culling* makes faces transparent/invisible when seen from the backside/inside, while *Alpha Transparency* results in alpha values of 0 shown in black, not transparent. Alpha values > 0 have no effect and will make the material look opaque.
3. In *Rendered* view, backface culling is disabled and doesn't effect the material, while *Alpha Transparency* will make the material more or less transparent according to the alpha value.